# Asp Date to Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Why is my date, when passed to the javascript function performing math operations on the values??

HTML:

```
<td><button type="submit" form="frmParams" onclick="ChangeDate(<% =Session("ECN") %>, <% =datStart3 %>);" value="Submit">Click Me To Change Date</button></td>
```

where Session("ECN") = '1111' and datStart3 = "6/02/2017"

Whenever I click this button, I my ajax request is for:

```
http://*****/apqp/updateDate.asp?ECN=1111&Date=0.001487357461576599
```

I want date to = "6/02/2017" (I have also tried replacing the '/' with '-' or 'a' with no luck)

The Javascript function:

```
function ChangeDate(strECN, strDate)
{
    // Get an xmlHTTPRequest object.  Jump out with an error if the object can't be created.
    xmlHTTP = getXMLHTTPObject();
    if(xmlHTTP == null){
        alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
        return;
    }

    strURL = './updateDate.asp?ECN=' + strECN + '&Date=' + strDate;

    // Setup the xmlHTTP object, open it & send the request.
    xmlHTTP.open("GET", strURL, false);
    xmlHTTP.send(null);

    // Display the line items.
    window.location.reload();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow, Im an idiot.

Just realized that I was passing it in as a Integer.

Putting '' around datStart3 in the HTML portion of :

```
<td><button type="submit" form="frmParams" onclick="ChangeDate(<% =Session("ECN") %>, <% =datStart3 %>);" value="Submit">Click Me To Change Date</button></td>
```

fixes it.